# For which values of $x$ is this function defined?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to find the domain of this function:

$$\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^2 -1}\right)^\left( \log_{e}{(6x^2\ +x\ \ -1)}\right)$$

I have tried this way:

$$\begin{Bmatrix}\frac{\sin x}{x^2-1} > 0\\6x^2 + x\ -1 > 0\\x\ne+1\quad\text ,\quad x\ne -1 \end{Bmatrix}$$

And I get $$-1<x<-\frac{1}{2}\quad \land \quad \frac{1}{3}<x<1\quad \land\quad\pi\ +\ 2k\pi\ < x <\ 2\pi\ +\ 2k\pi $$

Meanwhile the right solution is:

$$-1<x<-\frac{1}{2}\quad \land \quad \land\quad\pi\ +\ 2k\pi\ < x <\ 2\pi\ +\ 2k\pi $$

EDIT: it's $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Why is it required that $\frac {\sin x}{x^2\ -1}\gt 0$? Also, is your quadratic equation $6x^2+x+1$ or $6x^2+x-1$?

Comment: I think fixing the quadratic (like @anotherjohndoe said) will fix your answer

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-1} \gt 0$ because for $a^x$, $a$ must be greater than zero.

Comment: Right. It is defined for certain $x$ though? Integral powers and the like?

Comment: That is correct, but consider graphing it. The vast majority of the points are not on the real plane, and so it is better to just consider it as not defined when $a \lt 0$

Comment: Right. Thanks:)

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe '-1' sorry

Comment: @IDK Here's a graph of the function https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r28cbg9zd9

Comment: @JohnLou So the book solution is also wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right solution is not right.

The right solution is 
$$\left(1<x<\pi\right) \lor \left(2 \pi  k<x<(2k+1)\pi\right)\lor-1<x<-\frac{1}{2}$$

the first picture gives the solutions of $\frac{\sin x}{x^2-1}>0$

the second puts the previous  together with the  argument of logarithm which must be positive and shows the intersection of these intervals

the pictures don't show the multiple of $\pi$ solutions that are written above.

The domain is also $1<x<\pi$ try to plug some value and you will get real results

[image]

$$
.
$$
[image]

Comment: what kind of software did you use to make the graphics? Is it geogebra? Thanks.

Comment: @Ixion Yes, it is an "alternative" use of geogebra :)